# replace &nbsp; &amp; &copy; and another ISO-8859-1 by regex in php

Tags: php, regex

i need replace `&nbsp; &amp; &copy;` and another `&******;` and replace it to `""`
preg_replace or ereg_replace, i need some code

tried

```
$string = "one&nbsp;two&amp;three&copy;four";
$r = preg_replace('/^&+(\w)+;/', '--', $string);
echo $r;
```

it's incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the initial `^`. You want to match anywhere in the string, not just the start of the string.

```
preg_replace('/&+(\w)+;/', '--', $string);
 → string(21) "one--two--three--four"
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, this:

```
preg_replace('/&#?+(\w)+;/', '--', $string);
```

will cut out also numeric codes like `&#162;` and `&#x00A2;`.